# AMD Drivers on Linux Mint 21 (RX 6900 XT)

Tags: gpu, drivers

I've been having endless problems getting Blender to detect my graphics card.

It seems to be installed correctly per `inxi -G`

````
kennedy@beast:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 21 [Radeon RX 6800/6800 XT / 6900 XT] driver: amdgpu
    v: kernel
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu resolution:
    1: 6144x3456~60Hz 2: 2400x3840~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 6900 XT (sienna_cichlid LLVM 13.0.1 DRM
    3.47 5.19.5-051905-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5
    ```

Running kernel 5.19.5-051905-generic
````